# Yii - simplify retrieving the $_POST var data using getPost()

Tags: php, post, yii, http-post, yii-components

I have the following Yii code and would like to minimise it if possible:

```
$request = Yii::app()->request->getPost('request');
$username = $request['model']['username'];
```

Is it possible to minimise this to have this work something like this so its all on a single line for instance? (note the code below doesn't work)

```
$username = Yii::app()->request->getPost('request['model']['username']');
```

Answer (score 1):

as you can see below (in class *CHttpRequest*):

```
public function getPost($name,$defaultValue=null)
{
    return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue;
}
```

if you can put it in `$name`, it will get returned :D